# Python Pandas - Adding new sum to every row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python coding and I'm struggling to add a new column to my pandas framework.

Here's what the column looks like:
Time_Difference (it's in seconds)
3
2
5
6

It's a float64 type.
And what I wanna create is the following new column :
Duration
3
5
10
16

Actually in the format 00:00:00 (The duration adds up to about 2h since I'm tracking a run.)

Now, how to create a new column, that's clear but I struggle with the itterows() or apply() function.

In my naive perception, it should look something like this:
df["Duration"] = df["Time_Difference"] + df["Time_Difference"].shift(1)
Well, obviously it doesn't.

Couldn't find anything similar on stackoverflow as I don't wanna have the sum of the whole column but on every row.

Comment: Do you think `df["Duration"] = df["Time_Difference"].cumsum()` ?

Comment: Haha, that was easy. Thanks jezrael.